# GraphQL cannot find generated input type

Tags: swift, graphql

I wrote a mutation based on my 'Album' type:

```
mutation UpdateAlbum($updateAlbumId: String!, $albumUpdateInput: AlbumUpdateInput!) {
  updateAlbum(id: $updateAlbumId, albumUpdateInput: $albumUpdateInput) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

AlbumUpdateInput contains one property: 'name', which is a string.

After exporting the operation to my xCode project and building, I got an error:

```
Unknown type "AlbumUpdateInput". Did you mean "AlbumContent"?
file:///Users/ramy/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Developer/klikkie-concept/FavouritesPlus/GraphQL/Albums.graphql:38: error: Cannot query field "updateAlbum" on type "Mutation".
```

I can see that GraphQL doesn't recognise AlbumUpdateInput as a type, probably because it is not automatically generated. Does anybody know how to tell GraphQL to generate also this class?

Comment: Is `AlbumUpdateInput` defined in your GraphQL schema?

Comment: To be more exact, is AlbumUpdateInput an input type in your schema?

Answer (score 0):

In your GraphQL schema, first you need to create input type AlbumUpdateInput as follows:

```
input AlbumUpdateInput {
    name: String!
}
```

Then only you can access this input type.